# ActiveMQ Artemis Brokers behavior on trasaction commit error due to failover

Tags: activemq-artemis

We have encountered the following problem aka TransactionRolledBackException:

```
Transaction completion in doubt due to failover. Forcing rollback of ID:*****  at Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ.Connection.SyncRequest(Command command, TimeSpan requestTimeout)
   at Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ.Connection.SyncRequest(Command command)
   at Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ.TransactionContext.Commit()
   at Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ.Session.DoCommit()
   at Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ.Session.Commit()
```

Here's our topology: we have 6 nodes (n1, .., n6) where nodes n1, n3, n5 are clustered master nodes, and n2 is slave of n1, n4 is slave of n3, n6 is slave of n5.

We use transactions in sending and consuming message processes, which means that this exception could be thrown in both. I'm looking for best practices of handling TransactionRolledBackException without needing to rollback all the business logic executed before commit. We have our own application-level library, which allows fast and easy connection to the broker for sending/receiving messages, and we would like to implement into it some code which would handle TransactionRolledBackException for every application using it and provide "once and only once" delivery.

Thanks for your answers in advance

Comment: What do you mean by, "Caches are enabled..."? Are you talking about [duplicate ID caching](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/duplicate-detection.html)?

Comment: Even though these questions are related (i.e. they're about transactions) they're distinct. You need to narrow your question down more.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that duplicate detection and transactions are orthogonal. You can have one without the other. They are not conceptually related.

Comment: 1) yes, by "chaching" i mean "duplicate ID caching"
2) By those questions i'm trying to figure out if "duplicate ID caching" (or maybe other unmentioned Artemis tool) can fully handle TransactionRolledBackException in this topology. Cant understand what happens with messages on brokers side when i receive this exception on client during commiting the transaction. 
3) I tried to describe scenarios and circumstances when the error appears. Could you please tell me where am i not clear so i can explain my problem better

Comment: I think you should remove all the discussion of duplicate ID detection focus on the transaction issue directly. As I noted previously, duplicate ID detection and transactions are not conceptually linked. Transaction roll-backs are a normal part of broker/client operation and should be handled without issue.

Comment: well, we would like to avoid handling broker/network errors in each application connected to broker and implement general solution, which could guarantee (or almost guarantee) "once and only once" message delivery. I understand, that "duplicate ID detection" is not related to transactions, but wondering, if there are best practices on handling this particular exception on consumer/producer side.

Comment: The transaction itself is there to provide those kinds of guarantees. Furthermore, duplicate ID detection only applies to messages sent to a broker, not messages consumed from a broker so it only applies to half of your problem even in the best case. Once you modify your question I can address the transaction-specific concerns you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The transaction itself is there to provide the guarantees you're looking for (i.e. "once and only once").

Typically in the kind of situation you describe (where the consumption or production of a message or groups of messages needs to happen atomically with other business operations) all the resources involved in the atomic operation (e.g. JMS consumption, JMS production, JDBC inserts, JDBC deletes, etc.) are enlisted into the same transaction and managed by a transaction manager. That way when one of the individual operations fails then all the other work is automatically undone as well. Transactions like this are typically called XA transactions and are supported in both Spring and Java EE via the Jakarta/Java Transactions API (i.e. JTA).

In Java EE it is very common, for example, to have a Message Driven Bean (i.e. MDB) consume a message, work with a database, and then send another message so that every piece of that work is done atomically. If sending the message at the end fails then the database changes are reversed and the message the MDB consumed originally is put back on the queue to be consumed again in the future. In this way the message represents a kind of "unit of work" which is a simple, powerful pattern for managing business processes.

Comment: Well, I should metion it earlier, but we use .NET 6 with Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ nuget package. Our work with DB is based on Dapper ORM. 

We'd love to pivot whole message lifecycle to a "unit of work" pattern you described. 

So questions now are: 
1) We have failover node, but still got TransactionRolledBackException. According to you the message should be placed to failover queue and processed again, right? 
2) Do you know if Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ is integrated with .Net's transactions like it is in Java https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.transactions?view=net-6.0 ?

Comment: 1) If you're consuming a message and the transaction rolls back for _any_ reason then the message should still be on the queue (i.e. it shouldn't be consumed). If your brokers are configured with HA as a primary/backup pair then if your primary fails and the backup takes over then the message will still be on the backup. 2) No, I don't know if Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ is integrated with .Net's transactions.

Comment: Well, as you mentioned earlier, with duplicate ID detection we can be sure that message is enqueued in broker only once, so we can resent it until we get successful result of the commiting. But what happens if we just ignore TransactionRolledBackException during the consuming process? If we catch this exception and ignore it, the message won't rollback and not going to be consumed once again, right? Or this message is going to be consumed once again anyways?

Comment: If you send a message in a transaction and then that transaction is rolled back (causing a `TransactionRolledBackException` to be thrown) then you can rest assured that the message was not, in fact, sent. That guarantee is the point of using the transaction in the first place. Therefore, there's no point in using duplicate ID detection in that use-case.

Comment: Likewise, if you consume a message in a transaction and that transaction is rolled back then you can rest assured that the message was not, in fact, consumed. Therefore, the message will be consumed again. It doesn't matter whether or not you catch the `TransactionRolledBackException` and ignore it. The message will still be on the queue available for any consumer to receive. If rest of the work doesn't get rolled back along with the message consumption then that work will be duplicated when the message is consumed again. This is why folks use transactional resources and XA transactions.